# Updating software code on the repository

Tags: git

I've been working with an opensource software for some time, and I built a custom modification to it.
I have a public repository with a compilable version of that software+my modifications and now, I wanted to update the software to its newest version and insert my modifications.
How can I go about this, while removing the old version of the software from the repository (I realise it will still be available if the repository is reverted to a previous state)

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can only update the repository if you have the permission to do so. If you don't have the permission then you would need to fork the repository and then send a pull request". If the maintainers of the repository approve your modifications then it will be added to the repository.

Also, you can fork and create a new repo and keep your changes in the forked repo.

Edit: To save the changes to your local repository you need to use the following commands:

```
git add . //This adds all files you changed to staging area
git commit -m "Save changes" // The text in quotes is for describing the changes.. This commits your changes to local repo
```

Run these commands in your project directory and changes will be saved. Read the git basics chapter here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: I think you and @0xAX misunderstood my intentions... I have a local version of the software, and I modified that software. Now, I want to update the software on my repository to the latest version and patch it to include my changes. How can I do this without deleting the entire tree and place there the new version of the software+my patch?
Thank you both for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

If you want update it in the your local repo you can do following things:

If your changes are in separate branch from the `master`, you can just need to go to the master branch and update it with:

```
git checkout master
git pull remotename master
```

After this you can merge your changes with the updated master:

```
git merge my-branch
```

In the second case, if your changes are behind master, you can create new branch from master with your changes:

`git checkout -b "my-branch"`

Than you can reset your changes in the master with:

`git reset --hard HEAD~n`

where `n` is number of your commits. Than update master branch as I showed above and merge it with your branch:

```
git merge my-branch
```

In both cases you will get updated software with your changes. In other way if you want update it in the original repository, you will need in permissions as @Ankit Goel said.

Comment: Please see my comment to @Ankit Goel